# List gcp project resource types using api

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

Here I want to retrieve all the resources for a specific project or for the account using an java call (API call)  (eg-buckets, storage resources etc)

Answer (score 1):

There is no API call that will give you a list of all resources in a project as the different products use different API endpoints. You can however use the [Cloud Asset Inventory](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-asset-inventory/overview) to export all asset metadata at a certain point in time into a GCS file.